# How do I correctly order a Pandas series based on datetime

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

So to order my pandas dataframe, I have put this line of code for this specific output

```
airings_df = airings_df.sort_values(by=['Station', 'DateTime'])
```

The ordering for the station has worked, but it seems that times within the same hour are not being ordered correctly. What can I do to fix this?
[image: Picture of the output from the code block]

Comment: in the screenshot they are ordered, what makes you think the opposite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try converting the DateTime column to datetime format:

```
airings_df['DateTime']= pd.to_datetime(airings_df['DateTime'])
```

And then sort:

```
airings_df = airings_df.sort_values(by=['Station', 'DateTime'])
```